# How to create directory shortcut using windows shell32.dll in Java?

Tags: java, shortcut, shell32.dll

I need to create a batch file which can perform following actions.

1. Copied directories and sub directories from source folder older than 10 days to destination folders.
2. Delete copied directories from source folder and create short cuts for that in source folder.

Any help would be appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: If you want a batchfile, why did you tag the question with "java"? Create a powershell-script instead.

Comment: Hi ckuetbach! I want to create a batch file through java.

Answer (score 0):

Create a batch-file witout java and test ist until it works.

If the example batch file works, take a look how to create the batch with java.